# Resharper asp.net MVC live templates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper

Are there any ASP.NET MVC resharper live templates? I couldnt find any in google, you could post yours if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the embedded templates is rta, which stands for RedirectToAction, but with human order of placeholders to enter arguments - controller name first then action name. I think you could make a lot of such templates with normal order of arguments to fill.